# How can I get apple script to update the resolution scale on my Mac

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to get a service to work by using apple script to change the scale of my mac.

I've found this answer before:

[change screen resolution with AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014276/change-screen-resolution-with-applescript)

This is the script I got from it:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        set frontmost to true
        tell tab group 1 of window 1
            delay 1 -- (Added a delay to the original script as it didn't always succeed)
            click radio button 2 of radio group 1 -- "Scaled"
            select row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 -- select the second row in the table to change the resolution of the monitor
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

but it doesn't work for me. The image below shows the error I get and the option I want the script to select:

[image]

P.S. I also don't know how to write apple script and do not know how the GUI is named respectively with the context of the script.

Although any help to get this service working will be greatly appreciated. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
    click radio button "Scaled" of radio group 1 of tab group 1
    click radio button 2 of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Using Catalina 10.15.4 on a 2018 13" Macbook Pro this script toggles two resolution settings:

(Change the German words to your system language)

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell

set lowResolutionSettingIndex to 2
set highResolutionSettingIndex to 3

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Integriertes Retina-Display"
    click radio button "Monitor" of tab group 1
    click radio button "Skaliert" of tab group 1
    tell radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
        set isHighResolutionSet to get value of radio button highResolutionSettingIndex
    end tell
    if isHighResolutionSet then
        -- Toggle native resolution
        click radio button lowResolutionSettingIndex of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
    else
        -- Toggle Default setting - "Retina optimized"
        click radio button highResolutionSettingIndex of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
    end if
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"
```

---

This can be integrated into a Workflow and placed in the Touchbar as a button to toggle the switch.

Answer (score 0):

[displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) will allow you to programmatically choose any resolution/density that your monitor supports. This can be executed via a script or mapped to some hotkey.

For example, execute `displayplacer "id:<screenId> res:1440x900 scaling:on origin:(0,0) degree:0"` to set your screen resolution the red square in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I translated Johannes's script into English and customized it for MacBook Pro 16 inch:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell

set lowResolutionSettingIndex to 4
set highResolutionSettingIndex to 5

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
    click radio button "Display" of tab group 1
    click radio button "Scaled" of tab group 1
    tell radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
        set isHighResolutionSet to get value of radio button highResolutionSettingIndex
    end tell
    if isHighResolutionSet then
        -- Toggle native resolution
        click radio button lowResolutionSettingIndex of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
    else
        -- Toggle Default setting - "Retina optimized"
        click radio button highResolutionSettingIndex of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
    end if
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"
```